# Mutate/filter column which has same name as another dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, calculated-columns

I want to do something like this (a silly reprex):

```
iris %>%
    mutate(mtcars = Sepal.Length * 7) %>%
    filter(mtcars < max(mtcars$mpg))
```

where the first `mtcars` refers to a column in `iris`, while the second `mtcars` refers to the external data.frame.

I realise I could pre-compute `max(mtcars$mpg)` or simply relabel the data.frame, but I'm wondering if there is a way to distinguish between the two in situ explicitly?  E.g. something like:

```
iris %>%
    mutate(mtcars = Sepal.Length * 7) %>%
    filter(`mtcars` < max(EXTERNAL::mtcars$mpg))
#              ^                        ^
#            column               Not a column
```

Comment: for `EXTERNAL::mtcars$mpg`, you may have to determine you want the `mtcars` from the the `datasets` package, as in `datasets::mtcars$mpg`

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but I think this link - https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/dot-data.html - might be useful in discussing the `.data` and `.env` pronouns. Which seems to suggest `filter(mtcars < max(.env$mtcars))` should do what you want.

Comment: Indeed, `max(.env$mtcars$mpg)` works

Comment: @thelatemail, join the party ... your comment is canonical, post as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this link - https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/dot-data.html, the suggested method from the Tidyverse is to use the `.data` and `.env` pronouns to distinguish.

> The .data and .env pronouns make it explicit where to find objects
> when programming with data-masked functions.

So in this instance the code would be:

```
iris %>%
    mutate(mtcars = Sepal.Length * 7) %>%
    filter(mtcars < max(.env$mtcars$mpg))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works too.  How does `.env` and `.GlobalEnv` differ?  They both refer to the global environment right? Is `.env` just `rlang` shorthand for `.GlobalEnv`?

Comment: This would be my top pick for the correct answer.

Comment: @Earlien - As per the link, "`.env` is not an actual R environment" - but what it is exactly is not clear to me. Most of the *rlang* stuff goes totally above my head.

Comment: Based on @AllanCameron's comment and the fact it is the suggested method from the Tidyverse, I will accept this as the answer.  But other answers are great too.

Comment: I believe that `.env` behaves similar to my use of `get(.., envir=e)`: it looks immediately outside of the dplyr/mutate/<verbfun> environment to the calling environment and attempts to resolve there (and, as R does, search further in the search tree). For instance, if your `iris %>% ...` is inside of a function and you call that function from global, then `.env$..` will first look in your function (outside of `mutate`) and then in the global, stopping at the first match.

Answer (score 8):

If the "other" dataset is not part of a package, or you don't necessarily know the package a priori, you can use `get` with the environment that is outside of the dplyr pipe.

```r
e <- environment() # disposable after this next pipe
iris %>%
  mutate(mtcars = Sepal.Length * 7) %>%
  filter(mtcars < max(get("mtcars", envir = e)$mpg))
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species mtcars
# 1           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   32.9
# 2           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   32.2
# 3           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa   32.2
# 4           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa   30.8
# 5           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa   33.6
# 6           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa   33.6
# 7           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa   30.1
# 8           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa   32.2
# 9           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa   33.6
# 10          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa   32.9
# 11          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa   33.6
# 12          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa   30.8
# 13          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa   31.5
# 14          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   30.8
# 15          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa   33.6
# 16          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa   32.2
```

Using `e <- environment()` and then `envir = e`, we allow "local" (perhaps in-function) datasets to be used in this manner, not assuming or relying on global-env datasets or package datasets, etc.

Comment: Apart from the global environment, I'm not really familiar with how other environments arise.  I'll need to do more research (as linked above), I'll keep this in mind as an a more general solution in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in this case you can use `datasets::mtcars`

```r
iris %>%
  mutate(mtcars = Sepal.Length * 7) %>%
  filter(mtcars < max(datasets::mtcars$mpg))
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species mtcars
#> 1           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   32.9
#> 2           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   32.2
#> 3           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa   32.2
#> 4           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa   30.8
#> 5           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa   33.6
#> 6           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa   33.6
#> 7           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa   30.1
#> 8           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa   32.2
#> 9           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa   33.6
#> 10          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa   32.9
#> 11          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa   33.6
#> 12          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa   30.8
#> 13          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa   31.5
#> 14          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   30.8
#> 15          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa   33.6
#> 16          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa   32.2
```

A more general solution would be to reference the `environment` in which the dataset is found. For example, let's say the data frame was in your Global environment:

```r
iris %>%
  mutate(mtcars = Sepal.Length * 7) %>%
  filter(mtcars < max(.GlobalEnv$mtcars$mpg))
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species mtcars
#> 1           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   32.9
#> 2           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   32.2
#> 3           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa   32.2
#> 4           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa   30.8
#> 5           4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa   33.6
#> 6           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa   33.6
#> 7           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa   30.1
#> 8           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa   32.2
#> 9           4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa   33.6
#> 10          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa   32.9
#> 11          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa   33.6
#> 12          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa   30.8
#> 13          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa   31.5
#> 14          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   30.8
#> 15          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa   33.6
#> 16          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa   32.2
```

Comment: For completeness, do you believe we should add the possibility of a `.GlobalEnv$mtcars`, in case the data.frame is an object in the global env, @Allan? The OP obviously is not actually working with mtcars or iris

Comment: Just doing that as you wrote @GuedesBF! Though we have to import to the global environment first.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I was going down the road you are working on, AllanCameron ... if so, lmk and I'll delete mine.

Comment: I think your solution stands as another useful answer, @r2evans

Comment: Without looking, I wonder if the "canonical" (?) use of `.env` is implemented in this manner, but clearly more convenient to use. \*shrug*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  `.GlobalEnv` worked in my use case.

Comment: @r2evans no, I think your answer is different - it is more general. Possibly setting `pos = 2` in `get` instead of supplying `env` would prevent you having to pre-define a new environment though?

Comment: `pos=1` works as well ... I've never really be comfortable with `pos=` in environment stuff, though I haven't really _tried_ ...

Answer (score 3):

We can use `{{ }}` (curly-curly) operator, which is designed for programming with `dplyr`. It allows us to unquote variable names, making it clearer that you're referring to an object outside of the current data frame's scope.

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  mutate(mtcars = Sepal.Length * 7) %>%
  filter(mtcars < max({{ mtcars }}$mpg))
```