dplyr filter function not behaving as expected
I am trying to write a filter pipe using dplyr the way I always do, but its returning an empty dataframe. If I change the name of the variable I am filtering one, it works. I can't find anything special about the variable name I was using.
Here is some code to illustrate the problem:
#read in the data
x <- read.csv("output_data/final_data.csv")

This is what the data looks like:
str(x)
'data.frame':   263 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ proj.id   : chr  "P177038" "P176778" "P175745" "P175694" ...
 $ multiphase: num  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA 0 0 0 ...

#x has a variable in it called proj.id, and I want to filter for matches with proj.ids in the variable multiphase

#Confirm that some of the values in x$proj.id are in multiphase
> any(x$proj.id %in% multiphase)
[1] TRUE

#Try and use filter as I normally would - yields and empty dataframe
> x %>% filter(proj.id %in% multiphase) %>% dim()
[1] 0 2

#Try and do it without dplyr - yields a dataframe with 2 rows (as expected)
> x[x$proj.id %in% multiphase,] %>% dim()
[1] 2 2

#Checking there isn't some datatype issue, nothing shows up:
> class(multiphase) == class(x$proj.id)
[1] TRUE

Notably other uses of filter on the same data set work fine:
#I filter on another vector ("delayed") and get a dataframe with 13 rows as i expect
> x %>% filter(proj.id %in% delayed) %>% dim()
[1] 13  2

I try look for differences, but there are none
> class(delayed) == class(multiphase)
[1] TRUE

I try renaming multiphase (by invoking itself) and things work??!!
> multiphase_1 <- multiphase
> x %>% filter(proj.id %in% multiphase_1) %>% dim()
[1]  2 2

When i print(multiphase) i get what i expect
?multiphase yields nothing.
So i can fix this by renaming multiphase to something else, but why doesn't "multiphase" work as a variable name?

Please make your code reproducible, e.g. by including dput(x) or dput(head(x)).

Does your data frame have a multiphase column?  That would be consistent with the symptoms you're seeing. (filter would find the version of multiphase in x before the one in your global workspace)

Try proj.id %in% .env$multiphase as per this previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761757/mutate-filter-column-which-has-same-name-as-another-dataframe/77761804 - that should work if the issue is as Ben suggests.

@BenBolker thanks. That was the issue: i had a column named "multiphase" in x. Don't know why i missed that. Thanks so much.
